# Importing BTC/BCH paperwallet into Ledger Nano S

Tags: bitcoin-cash, paper-wallet, hardware-wallet

Can and how does one import a paper wallet (private key) that contained BTC before the hardfork and now BCH as well into a ledger nano s to split them? Or do they have to be split in another wallet first and then tranfered separately? I've contacted Ledger support but it takes weeks to get a response.

Answer (score 2):

The Ledger Nano S doesn't support importing private keys [because](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1811021.msg21053150#msg21053150) that would [defeat the purpose of it being a hardware wallet](https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/6z5lly/q_importing_private_keys_from_electrum_wallet_to/):

> (ie: your computer might have had malware at some point, and your keys could have been compromised without your knowledge)